# Android unit test for Enum type

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, enums

I came across something strange.
Example of function:

```
public class F {
  public enum Pawn {Black, White}

  public Pawn x;
  public F(){
      this.x = Pawn.Black;
  }
  public Pawn test(){
      return this.x;
  }
}
```

Unit test for this:

```
import junit.framework.Assert;
import junit.framework.TestCase;

import <package ... >.F;

public class FTest extends TestCase {
    public void testValue(){
        F mF = new F();
        Assert.assertSame(Pawn.Black, mF.test());
    }
}
```

And JUnit output:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected same:<Black> was not:<Black>

Expected :Black
Actual   :Black
```

Black is not black and is black. It's black magic. :/
What can I do to make this work (i.e. pass test)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need AssertEquals, not AssertSame

> assertEquals(java.lang.Object expected, java.lang.Object actual) 
>        Asserts that two objects are equal.
>
> assertSame(java.lang.Object expected, java.lang.Object actual) 
>        Asserts that two objects refer to the same object

Your code is comparing the object F.x against the enum object Pawn.Black. It should be

```
public void testValue(){
    F mF = new F();
    Assert.assertEquals(F.Pawn.Black, mF.test());
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I just tested it and it worked against Junit 4. I had to make a reference to F.Pawn.Black rather than Pawn.Black, did not compile otherwise. With enums AssertSame would probably work as well, they are a bit like String literals, but for clarity assertEquals is better.

Comment: Thanks. Also: assertSame is working, but i will remember to use assertEquals.